# Looking for an older note taking application that worked with tabular entry

Tags: windows, note-taking, information-management, personal-information-management

I once had a piece of software, that was free and as i recall even open source, that was a revolutionary concept allowing you to enter information as tables. And each cell could then have sub-cells in itself, thus creating a grid for your information. I was shown this by a colleague at the time and we used it on a project. I loved that way of entering information, and i remember it had short cut keys that you could use to swiftly add columns and rows etc. as you where typing. I think my colleague also used it to link information between sections and so on. It was quite unique in its way of entering text.

But now to my problem. I want to use it again now, but i can not for the life of me remember the name of this software. I've tried all sorts of google fu, but "tab based notes", "table note taking" etc. yields no result.

Does ANYONE remember something like this? It's a standalone desktop application and we ran it on Windows at the time. I'm losing my mind here trying to remember...

Answer (score 2):

Found it thanks to my old colleague. It's called TreeSheets by Google Engineer Wouter van Oortmerssen.

Link to it:

https://strlen.com/treesheets/